# Variable is lost when passed as a parameter in setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a problem with calling a function with a parameter inside a setTimeout function. Basically I'm trying to make a small online game, where I create a queue of commands and then execute them one at a time (each takes some time to show a visualization).

Unfortunately it seems that I cannot pass any variable as a parameter inside the setTimeout(). Although the variable does exist when I call the function it does not exist later when it is executed. The function doesn't keep track of the passed value.

Is there any solution to this? Thanks a lot for any help. Here is a code I use:

```
function executeCommands() {
    var commands = document.getElementsByClassName("cmdplace");
    var timeout = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
        console.log(commands[i].childNodes[0]); //variable exists
        setTimeout(function() {go(commands[i].childNodes[0]);}, timeout+=400);  //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined
        console.log(commands[i].childNodes[0]); //variable still exists
    }
}

function go(command) {
    //do somethig based on the passed command
}
```

Comment: what is go()?..

Comment: Ah, sorry. go() is my function that does something based on the passed command.

Comment: @PetrHofman, you can see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your functions are invoked, `i` is equal to `commands.length` and `commands[i]` is `undefined`.
They are capturing the variable `i`, not its value.
When they execute, they get out of `i` the actual value, but so far it has reached `commands.length` (that is the condition used to break your loop).

You can do something like this to work around it:

```
setTimeout(function(j) {
    go(commands[j].childNodes[0]);
}.bind(null, i), timeout+=400);
```

Or this:

```
setTimeout((function(j) {
    return function() {
        go(commands[j].childNodes[0]);
    };
})(i), timeout+=400);
```

Note also that, as you defined it, `i` is a global variable.

---

As mentioned in the comments by @PMV, there's a much easier way in modern JavaScript (if that's an option for you).
Just use a `let` statement as it follows:

```
for (let i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
    // do whatever you want here with i
}
```

This will ensure that each iteration gets a new variable named `i` and you can capture it as in the original code.

Comment: There's a much easier way with ES6: just use a `let` statement:  `for (let i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {`.  This will ensure each iteration gets a new variable named `i` to capture.

Comment: @PMV Right. I'm adding the comment with a mention to the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Petr hofman please read this https://community.risingstack.com/explaining-javascript-closure-scope-chain-examples/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a distinct copy of each item. By the time the `setTimeout` runs the loop has already finished.

```js
var timeout = 0;

function executeCommands() {
    var commands = document.getElementsByClassName("cmdplace");
    
    for (i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
          go(commands[i]);
    }
}

function go(command) {
  setTimeout(function() {
     console.log(command);
  }, timeout += 400);  
}

executeCommands();
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="cmdplace">A</li>
  <li class="cmdplace">B</li>
  <li class="cmdplace">C</li>
  <li class="cmdplace">D</li>
</ul>
```